# Working SQL client

Tags: 14.04, apache2, mysql

I managed to get working Apache and everything's fine.
Got MySQL running, which is nice. But then it turned out that I had to use terminal for all the SQL commands I had to put inside. I'm not close to that good to manage database by commands. So I wanted to use phpmyadmin, which prompted thousands errors and I can't even look into a table I just set up.

Does somebody know Ubuntu friendly MySQL database manager?

Answer (score 4):

Universal database managers
a) DBeaver

```
wget -c http://dbeaver.jkiss.org/files/dbeaver_3.4.5_i386.deb
sudo dpkg -i dbeaver_3.4.5_i386.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

b) Valentina Studio

```
wget -c https://www.valentina-db.com/en/studio/download/current/vstudio_x64_lin-deb?format=raw
sudo dpkg -i vstudio_5_lin.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Valentia, looked great, but it's not, that, it's no where as easy as phpmyadmin. I managed to create database and then I wanted to create table and I was doomed by my stupidity. For second. DBeaver, I managed to install him through terminal, as your commands suggested, but I couldn't find him, also through dash.

Comment: type in terminal `whereis dbeaver`. It will localte your binary. /usr/share/dbeaver/dbeaver

Comment: "dbeaver:" is output.

Comment: The download link for valentina-db is no more working.It might have been changed.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the question is not about the category "GUI clients that make writing SQL statements easier", but "clients that *avoid* SQL or generate it for you".

So, relevant products would have wizards, or query builders, or table builders, or QBE.

`phpMyAdmin` has already been excluded, and `MySQL Workbench` has already been mentioned.

Non-WINE possibilities are

1. `SQLeo Visual Query Builder` (requires Java)
2. `Open Office Base` [OpenOffice Base website- creating tables](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/OOoAuthors_User_Manual/Getting_Started/Creating_database_tables)
3. `Adminer` [Adminer offical website](https://www.adminer.org/) (requires php).

I am not a user of these products, I am only suggesting that they might fit the question.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It would be more useful if you could elaborate a little more about the three options you have given.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Mysql Workbench:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-workbench
```

This lives in universe, so you have to enable universe repository for that to work.
That said, if you are going to code anything (esp. SQL), you will need to get used to command line.

Comment: "That said, if you are going to code anything (esp. SQL), you will need to get used to command line.", oh no...

Comment: I tried MySQL Workbench already. It's not really a GUI, it's more like, just GUI to connect and then type it in. I know how to login through terminal already and list databases.

Answer (score 0):

There's also [SQuirreL SQL](http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/#installation).

It requires Java, so you might need to run first:

```
apt-get install openjdk-7-jre
```